# How do I get past Grub and boot into windows?

Tags: grub2, software-uninstall

I went to go uninstall Ubuntu from my laptop because it wasn't dealing with 2 operating systems and such. A tutorial I read on how to uninstall said Ubuntu can be Uninstaller with going into the uninstall menu on windows. Sure enough it wasn't there. So I go back to the article and it shows another way to uninstall, and I followed it. The only thing is, when it told me to create a recovery USB and restart the computer, grub pops up and I can't get through. Please help it is my only current computer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Comment: what was this 'another way' to uninstall that you followed, and from which tutorial?